# Как изменить название приложения уже готового проекта?

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore

Есть приложение, которое уже выложено в AppStore. Не устраивает то, что название у него под иконкой пишется на английском `SvadbaPRO`. Хочется поменять эту надпись на русскую `Свадьба ПРО`.

В связи с этим вопрос - как и где это можно сделать и будет ли при перелазивке новой версии уже существующего проекта, приложение с новым именем расцениваться AppStore как ровно то же самое, а не абсолютно новое с новым именем (не даст произвести апгрейд/еще что-нибудь...)?

Если попробовать выразиться совсем простым языком: где меняется в Xcode надпись, которая отображается под иконкой установленного приложения? Можно ли эту версию заливать как новую версию поверх приложения со старой надписью?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Чтобы изменить название приложения под иконкой, необходимо в файле `info.plist` в параметре "Bundle display name" вписать то что вы хотите.

Если вы хотите именно локализовать это название, чтобы по-английски было одно, а по-русски другое, тогда нужно создать в проекте свой файл `InfoPlist.strings`, локализовать этот файл под разные языки, и вписать туда такой параметр:

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "App name";
```

Где "App name" - это название вашего приложения на определённом языке. После чего необходимо в том же файле `info.plist` в строке "Bundle display name" вписать `${PRODUCT_NAME}`

Чтобы локализовать название в App Store, необходимо в itunes connect создать новую версию приложения, затем добавить языки. И для каждого языка вписать название.